# Why SHA256 digest of Docker image changes if we push the same image with same tag multiple times to the same docker repository

Tags: docker, dockerfile, artifactory

I have created a docker image with a custom tag using Dockerfile. For the first time when I pushed it to docker repository (in Jfrog artifactory) using docker push command, it generated a SHA256 digest value. Now I again pushed the same image with same tag without any change in the content of the image to the same docker repository. But now it generated new SHA256 digest value.

Can someone explain me why this is happening? I'm struck at this point as my project is hardly dependent to SHA256 digest value of the docker image.

Comment: @user1529891 - Thanks alot. That answered my question

Comment: I aws latest version (2021) if  I push the same source code with new tag, digest is the same. I would want a new digest, just as your question

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Since my comment answered your question, original credit goes to the post here: https://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/

Layers are identified by a digest in this form: `algorithm:hex` which looks like `sha256:abcd....`.

The `hex` is calculated by applying the algorithm (`sha256`) to the layers content. If the content changes, then the digest changes.

Comment: Can you give some more information related to how manifest.json gets created and what is the information it consists of? Because of the change in manifest.json the overall SHA value of the image is getting changed even if there is no change in content of layers

Comment: This answer is very confusing. The content doesn't change does it? I mean we are just tagging something, we aren't changing the thing that is being tagged. So unless the tags of an image are somehow part of that image, then this isn't really an explanation at all.

Comment: @Kris Changing text in files does mean the content has not changed. When you build an image, there are a lot layers (e.g. SO updates, parent image changes, etc) So at least you have all the layers cached the content will change often even if your code is the same.